# Strange behaviour while reading file from Java

Tags: java, matrix

I am having some problems while reading from a file. I'm trying to read from a text file and read and write the chars into a matrix. The problem is that I got an IndexOutOfBounds exception and I dont know why this happens.

This is my code:

```
public static char[][] readTxt(String args[]) {
    String file = args[0];
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line = br.readLine();

        //counter
        int counter = 0;

        String[] tam = line.split(",");

        char[][] maze = new char[tam.length][tam.length];

        while (line != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");

            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                maze[counter][i] = values[i].charAt(0);
            }
            counter++;
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
        return maze;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception reading file " + file + ": " + e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

It throws IndexOutOfBounds in `char[][] maze = new char[tam.length][tam.length];`

My input looks like this:

`%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%
 %,C, , , ,C, , ,C, ,%
 %,%,%, , , ,%,%,%,%,%
 %,C, , , ,C, , , , ,%
 %, , , , , , , , , ,%
 %, , , , , , , , , ,%
 %, , , , , , , , , ,%
 %, , , , , , , , , ,%
 %, , , , , , , , , ,%
 %, , , , , , , , , ,%
 %,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%`

I also tried to change it to:

```
 char[][] maze = new char[tam.length+1][tam.length+1];
```

And now it works, but i dont know why. Any ideas?

PD: when I printed the matrix, I saw something strange. It looks like it printed some blank characters at the right side of my matrix, but in my input file I dont wrote any blank characters :(

[my matrix in java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AukWn.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: Your first line is already read.

Comment: Where does `linea` come from?

Comment: what is the data in the file actually?

Comment: @Thomas Böhm sorr i fixed that, its line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your assumption, that you always have as much lines as you have entries within a line correct?

I would not place the calls to `readLine` so far apart from each other. Did you know that you could write something similar also with streams and with [nio.Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)?

Your code somehow different, without the need to check for the counters:

```
Character[][] maze = Files.lines(Paths.get(stringPathOrUri))
      .map(s -> s.split(","))
      .map(strings -> Stream.of(strings)
                            .map(s -> s.charAt(0)) // better: insert your transformation function here
                            .toArray(Character[]::new))
      .toArray(Character[][]::new);
```

This can still be improved, but you may get the idea.